# SQL PHP ARRAY echo single array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm trying to echo out an array but for some reason I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be long, string
>   given in login.php on line 25

Here's my code could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong!

```
if(isset($_POST['loginform'])){ 
        $username = $_POST['login-username'];
        $userpassword = $_POST['login-password'];

        $sql = "SELECT    *
FROM         dbo.system_users
WHERE     (user_name = '$username') AND (user_password = '$userpassword') AND (active = 1)";

        $sql1 = "SELECT        dbo.system_orgs.org_id, dbo.system_orgs.org_name
FROM            dbo.system_orgs INNER JOIN
                         dbo.system_users ON dbo.system_orgs.org_id = dbo.system_users.user_orgid
WHERE user_name = '$username' AND user_password = '$userpassword')";

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1 );

        $count=sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);      
        $org=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1);

        if($count==1){
            $_SESSION['user']=$org;
            echo $org['org_id'];
            //header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            $loginresults = "
                <div class='alert alert-danger' role=alert>
                    error
                </div>";
        }
}

?>
```

I'm currently for testing purposes only trying to echo out the org_id but I will be echoing out the org_name also.

Comment: What does `var_dump($stmt1)` show?

Comment: @Barmar currently outputs "boolean false"

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are also assuming your queries can never fail. Both are very bad.

Comment: That means you're getting an error in the query. Check the SQL error.

Comment: You definitely never should pass the argument given by the user directly into the SQL-String! This is a big invitation to all kind of hacking. MarkB is right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @flaschenpost I'm currently in the testing phase, I'll be applying all checks and / strips etc later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, you are getting an error in your query, try checking them as follows:

```
//...your code
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1 );
if( $stmt1 === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
   //...your code...
}
//...your code
```

With this you should get more info about why the query is failing and probably you will know how to fix it.